# Convert hours into minutes

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the hours into minutes.

Example: If `hour` is `2:18`, then I want the output as `138` minutes.

```
<script>
m = diff % 60;
h = (diff - m) / 60;

mins = h.toString() + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") + m.toString();
alert(mins)
</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `diff`?

Comment: And your code does... the opposite? Therefore: what have you tried?

Comment: `var val = (hours * 60)+minutes;` ?

Comment: @Satpal diff=2:18

Comment: @noushadmohammed: Do you mean `diff == "2:18"`? `2:18` on its own is a syntax error.

Comment: @ProEvilz how to split hours and minutes from the variable diff? because the output is like 2:18

Comment: @noushadmohammed: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. How do you split a string into parts? How do you turn those parts into numbers? These questions are **easily** researched. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I assumed m = minutes and h = hours and you would use those individually instead of taking the formatted time

Comment: @ProEvilz ok bro

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert this into javascript. Following code might help you

```
var hms = '2:18';   // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var minutes= (+a[0]) * 60  + (+a[1])  ; 

console.log(minutes);
```

Comment: thank you bro. its working fine. but why you used +a  ?

Comment: + is javascript  shortcut  to convert a string to  number

Comment: but if i remove + before a in both place then it wil output 2400 instead of 240

Comment: @noushadmohammed Yes? What are you asking here?

Comment: you can use parseInt  or parseFloat instead of +